# Python Convert a table of strings to datetime

Tags: python

Quote_data1 is a table consisted with a column of datetime in string and other information
datetime format: 2016-10-03T07:30:01.000Z

I want to convert this table to datetime format(and then rank them), so can someone identify the error of my code?

```
l = len(Quote_data1)
Time = np.zeros((l,1))
DateTime = Quote_data1['DateTime']
for k in range(1,l):
    Time[k] = datetime.strptime((DateTime[k]), '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.000Z')
Time
```

==============================================================================
update:
How Can I filter this list of DateTime to a range of 11am to 15pm?

1   2016-10-03T07:30:01.000Z    Q   84.65   87.81   2016-10-03 07:30:01

2   2016-10-03T07:30:02.000Z    Q   88.22   87.81   2016-10-03 07:30:02

3   2016-10-03T07:30:03.000Z    Q   88.22   87.81   2016-10-03 07:30:03

4   2016-10-03T07:30:08.000Z    Q   88.22   87.81   2016-10-03 07:30:08

5   2016-10-03T07:30:33.000Z    Q   88.22   87.81   2016-10-03 07:30:33

`Quote_data2['Time'].indexer_between_time(start='11:15', end='15:00')`

Quote_data2 is the table;
   Time is the DateTime (last colume), datetime.datetime(2016, 10, 3, 7, 30, 1) format

Comment: Do you really need to convert it into datetime format? Because the way it is written (`2016-10-03T07:30:01.000Z`) is meant for not needing to convert to `date`. You can just run normal string compare. `'2016-01-01T08:00:00' < '2016-01-01T08:00:01'` results in `True`...

Comment: Thank you so much for the comment. May I ask a followup question? If I got a table with a few columns with column label (Name,DateTime,Price,etc), and I want to filter the DateTime(2016-01-01T08:00:01) to only 11am-3pm and sort the table in time order. Do you have any idea how to achieve this? Many thanks

Comment: i will answer as an answer so that i can use better coding...

Comment: what about date? can it be any?

Comment: Please update question to your new code

Answer (score 0):

### Question 1

First you have to ask yourself whether you really need to convert it to datetime format. Because the way it is written (`2016-10-03T07:30:01.000Z`) is meant for not needing to convert to datetime format in order to make comparisons. You can run normal string compare like this:

```
>> '2016-01-01T08:00:00' < '2016-01-01T08:00:01'
True
```

### Question 2 (in comments to question)

You want to filter the results to only those that are between 11am and 3pm. You can do it with following command

```
SELECT * FROM your_table
WHERE
DateTime LIKE '%T11%' OR
DateTime LIKE '%T12%' OR
DateTime LIKE '%T13%' OR
DateTime LIKE '%T14%'
ORDER BY DateTime;
```

It might look ugly but any other "neater" solution would take more effort which is really unnecessary since the answer above is really short.

This will of course match times between 11am and 3pm on any given date.

If this was supposed to be achieved with Python, you want something like this:

```
matches = [ line for line in your_table if \
               'T11' in your_table['DateTime'] or
               'T12' in your_table['DateTime'] or
               'T13' in your_table['DateTime'] or
               'T14' in your_table['DateTime'] ]
```

if `your_table` looks like this

```
your_table = [ { 'DateTime': '2016-01-01T08:08:08', 'user': ... }, \
               { 'DateTime': ... }
```